# Configure service to Delayed Auto-Start (and Auto-start on XP/2003)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX script, that does installation of service. I have following `ServiceInstall` element under `Component`.

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"
                Name="abc" DisplayName="abc service"
                Description="It does this" Start="auto"
                Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no">
  <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall ="yes" />
</ServiceInstall>
```

And as seen from the code, I am using `ServiceConfig` with **`DelayedAutoStart`** flag to set the service to start in delayed auto start mode. However the WiX compiler (`candle.exe`) triggers a warning:

> warning CNDL1150: ServiceConfig functionality is documented in the
>   Windows Installer SDK to "not [work] as expected." Consider replacing
>   ServiceConfig with the WixUtilExtension ServiceConfig element.

Hence, I tried using `util:ServiceConfig`^, however this element doesn't have any attribute to control service startup.

**^** Namespace import:

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

Hence, the questions are simply:

1. How to set service startup to be Automatic (Delayed Start)?
2. How to conditionally do it only on Vista and above, and do normal (Automatic) on Windows XP/2003?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking the [source](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/master/src/ext/ca/wixca/dll/serviceconfig.cpp) it does not seem possible at the moment. Wix calls the [ChangeServiceConfig2 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx) only with the `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` parameter and not with `SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO`.

If I was you, I'd write a custom action calling `sc config abc start=delayed-auto` in a CMD.

As for your second question add VersionNT version condition (`VersionNT >= 600` for all version greater than Vista)

Comment: Then ideally it shouldn't give that warning.

Comment: Downvoted because the source code linked to is for WIX's `UtilExtension` `<util:ServiceConfig />` element (with the `FirstFailureActionType` attribute) and not the original MSI `<ServiceConfig />` element (with the `DelayedAutoStart` and `OnInstall` attributes)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote @Dai. However, the OP does use the UtilExtension, and as you can easily see, candle.exe triggers a warning when using ServiceConfig as also documented by the OP.
I gladly accept a downvote, but please also be so kind and offer a better answer to the OPs problem.

Comment: Does anyone know this issue has been resolved in the latest release?

Comment: I found a replacement in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763596/how-to-change-the-windows-service-startup-type-in-a-wix-installer mentioned as below, not sure if it is a fixed. <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[ServiceName]"
               Type="integer" Name="DelayedAutostart" Value="1"/>

Comment: `<ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall ="yes" />` works as expected here, my service is installed as delayed auto start

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: are you using the one from `http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension`? Cause that is what caused the warning in the OPs question.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall No, because `util:ServiceConfig` doesn't support `DelayedAutoStart`. So both I and the asker are using the standard WiX `ServiceConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the vanilla ServiceConfigworks , Infact i am using both ServiceConfig,(from utils and from wix) inside a service

```
<util:ServiceConfig
          
        FirstFailureActionType="restart"
        SecondFailureActionType="restart"
        ThirdFailureActionType="restart"
        RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="0"
         
     />
    <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall ="yes" />
```