# Set service Startup type in WiX installer

Tags: service, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to set a pre-installed service's startup type to `Automatic`, using WiX. Another task was to start the service on install, which I achieved with:

```
<ServiceControl 
    Id="ServiceRunningState" 
    Name="[Service Name]" 
    Start="install"
    Stop="install"
    Wait="yes" />
```

Now I would also like to set the startup type. I have tried the following (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158372/5387193)):

```
<ServiceConfig
    Id="ServiceStartup" 
    ServiceName="[Service Name]"
    DelayedAutoStart="yes"
    OnInstall="yes" 
    OnReinstall="yes" />
```

But this didn't change the startup type of the service (tested from `Manual` startup type). And besides, I want the startup type to be `Automatic`, not `Automatic (Delayed Start)`.

Please note that I am trying to modify an *existing service*, so there is no `ServiceInstall` element.

The two elements (`ServiceControl` and `ServiceConfig`) are children within a `Component` parent element.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by editing the registry via `RegistryKey`, see example:

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
             Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[Service Name]"
             Action="create">
    <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Start" Value="2" />
    <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="DelayedAutostart" Value="0" />
</RegistryKey>
```

Note service may appear as `Automatic (Delayed Start)` in Services GUI. However, after restarting, Services GUI displayed the service startup type as `Automatic`.

Answer (score 2):

MSI doesn't support changing the startup type of a service that the package doesn't install. `ServiceConfig` [doesn't let you get around that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Applies only to installed auto-start services or services installed by this package with SERVICE_AUTO_START in the StartType field of the ServiceInstall table.

Comment: I thought as much. Why do they even let you access the `ServiceConfig` outside of a `ServiceInstall` element if the functionality won't work, seems kind of counterproductive. The question doesn't explicitly ask for `ServiceConfig` solutions, but I appreciate the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the "DelayedAutoStart" parameter to "no", rather than "yes".